# "Resolved" Retrofit with Kotlin does not trigger enqueue

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

[Please check the update 2]

I'm trying to implement retrofit with Kotlin. Please look at the following code:

Here is the main retrofit method which should get the user from API(Webservice):

```
const val BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"

fun getUser(userId: Int){
    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .build()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

     val user = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)

        val userObject : Call<ResponseBody> =  user.getUser(userId)

        userObject.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                e(javaClass.simpleName, "loginResponse: $call")
                e(javaClass.simpleName, "loginResponse: ${t.printStackTrace()}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                e(javaClass.simpleName, "loginResponse: ${response.raw()}")
                e(javaClass.simpleName, "loginResponse: ${response.code()}")
                e(javaClass.simpleName, "loginResponse: ${response.message()}")
            }

        })

}
```

Api interface:

```
interface Api {

    @GET("users/{id}")
    fun getUser(
        @Path("id") id: Int
    ): Call<ResponseBody>
}
```

Now the issue is with the callback method of enqueue, onResponse and onFailure does not print any logs. But I get the logs the Http request is successful from OkHttpClient. If I use equivalent java code everything works just fine. I've spent an entire day searching for the solution. and tried different approaches, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

For now, I'm using it's equivalent Java code as follows which works great:

```
    userObject.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NotNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            e(TAG, "loginResponse: " + call);
            e(TAG, "loginResponse: " + response.string());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
            e(TAG, "loginResponse: " + call);
            e(TAG, "loginResponse: ", t);
        }
    });
```

Though I'm keeping this question unresolved, somebody might find/know a solution for it. Or If I find it in future I'll update it.

**UPDATE 2**

It was a silly mistake, or I can't even say it was a mistake. Actually what happened is logs were not getting printed from those methods. But when I put Toast inside those methods, it displayed the toast with the response.

**So, I learned that Android Logs are not always reliable, so when you're stuck with the logs, always try and use toasts or interface methods. So this is the answer to my question.**

But anybody could tell me why those logs didn't print, that would be very helpful too.

Comment: I am using Retrofit with Kotlin, and its perfectly fine. What error do you get? Your code seems fine though.

Comment: Yes, code is fine, updated my post, there's must be some bug related to Logs or retrofit I think.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and had to make some changes for it to work.

First, I had to define my own `data class ResponseBody(val id: Int, val name: String)` class (I was too lazy to add all fields). It did not work when I used `okhttp3.ResponseBody`.

And to get it to print the data that is returned, you have to change `${response.message()}` to `${response.body()}`.

In the Java code you posted, you use `response.string()`, which is different from `response.message()` in your Kotlin code.

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising, I'll test this in a while and let you know!

Comment: Sounds good! Let me know if you get further problems, I will help you debug them!

Comment: Hello Enselic, I tried this way, but no doesn't work, can you please add the code you've tried maybe I'm making some small silly mistake somewhere.

Comment: Here is my entire code: https://pl.kotl.in/r0jGiiNKX When I run that I see this in the logs: `E         : loginResponse: ResponseBody(id=1, name=Leanne Graham)` and the name `Leanne Graham` clearly comes from the HTTP response. Hopefully this works for you too! I run my code in a newly created Android project.

Comment: I've tried this code in my existing project, did not work. I'll create a new demo project tonight and will check if it's working. Thanks

Comment: Bdw I'm using Kotlin 1.3.41, do you think it's related to that?

Comment: @ParagPawar I also use Kotlin 1.3.41 so shouldn't be that

Comment: Ohh man, I was getting data all along, it wasn't just getting printed using logs. when I put Toast in those methods. toast displayed with a response. Such a silly mistake, but I wonder why those logs did not get print?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200256/discussion-between-enselic-and-parag-pawar).

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your method parameters as nullable;

```
userObject.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, t: Throwable?) {
            e(javaClass.simpleName, "loginResponse: $call")
            e(javaClass.simpleName, "loginResponse: ${t.printStackTrace()}")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, response: Response<ResponseBody>?) {
            e(javaClass.simpleName, "loginResponse: ${response.raw()}")
            e(javaClass.simpleName, "loginResponse: ${response.code()}")
            e(javaClass.simpleName, "loginResponse: ${response.message()}")
        }

    })
```

Since the Callback interface is defined in java those parameters are not nonnull.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but nope, just tried it, does not work.